# ajax .keyup search function

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

I have a search function that uses the .keyup method on a rails application. I know that the call is working because the first letter I type is searching and showing results. If I continue to type it doesn't continue to search the method. Here is my jquery below and the part of my rails view it is calling.

**JQuery**

```
    $("input#search").keyup(function (){
    $.get($("#verified_search").attr("action"), $("#verified_search").serialize(), null, "script");
    return false;
});
```

**index.js.erb**

```
$(".results").html("<%= escape_javascript(render("search")) %>");
```

**index.html.erb view**

```
 <%= form_tag admin_view_index_path, :method => 'get', :id => 'verified_search' do %>
            <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
            <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => :nil %>
 <% end %>

 <%= render 'search' %>
```

Comment: If you continue typing whether new request are sent to the server?

Comment: One thing you have have to do is to `abort` the previous search before sending a new request if required

Comment: There are requests that are sent but no information. On my initial search, my first letter is a "j". It gives me Parameters: { "search => "j", "_" => "1361982841588"}. On the next letter types it updates my server but no information in the Paramters. Looks like so Parameters: { "_" => "1361982850183"}.

Comment: How do you abort a previous search after the sent request?

Comment: Something like `var xhr;

$(function(){
 $("input#search").keyup(function (){
  if(xhr && xhr.readystate != 4){
   xhr.abort();
  }
  xhr = $.get($("#verified_search").attr("action"), $("#verified_search").serialize(), null, "script");
  return false;
 });
});`

Comment: After reading I found that the .abort has to be on a true ajax call and not a jquery .on or .load which I am using.

Answer (score 0):

Use `.live()`

```
$("input#search").live('keyup', function (){
  $.get($("#verified_search").attr("action"), $("#verified_search").serialize(), null, "script");
  return false;
});
```

When you replace the content of `$('.results')` in index.js.erb, any listeners associated with those elements are gone.

http://api.jquery.com/live/

**Edit: As it says in the link, the `.live()` method is deprecated as of jQuery 1.7. Use `.on()` to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use `.delegate()` in preference to `.live()`.**

Comment: Even with the .live function after my first letter input it does the search but doesn't continue to update the content. Actually a more detailed description is after I type my first letter, lets say "J". It gives me the results, if I type further, i.e. "ja" it clears out my search and loads the original page and stops searching.

Comment: I have also used the .on() and "submit" event with it. It only allows one search. I believe it is coming somewhere in what's being loaded. When I do the .on("submit",....) it does the ajax function once and then when I type to search another name it won't search anything.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).on("keyup", "#verified_search", function(){
       $.get($("#verified_search").attr("action"), $("#verified_search").serialize(), null, "script");
       return false;
   });
```